# How to create a web app with data from import.io

Tags: javascript, web-applications, import.io

I am fairly new to web dev and I know the basics of html, CSS, JavaScript and jQuery, so just front end.
As a challenge to learn more I want to create a web app that does the following:

1. Get the pictures, description, link and price of rent properties from various sites. For web scraping I would use `import.io` to get the data I want and then query that API to manipulate and show the data.
2. With this data I want to create an aggregator app that would show all the properties querying the `import.io` database let's say every 15 minutes to get new properties.

My question is how do I do that? What languages I need to learn? Or is just a matter of getting the data from `import.io` API in JSON form and then displaying it in html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it' just a matter of getting the data from import.io and display them.
You could create your API in import.io and then do an ajax call in your app

```
$.ajax({
     "url":"https://api.import.io/store/connector/<yourimport.ioapi>",
     "crossDomain": true,
     "dataType": "json",

     'success': function(response){ 
    //do what you want with the data
    }
}
```

Or you could export the data to Google Sheets or plot.ly. You could schedule the API to get new data on a daily or weekly base so it won't make sense to look every 15 min for new data. The scheduler is also a beta feature.